# Handle TabLayout tab click

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have a Fragment with TabLayout and ViewPager in it:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="layout.LinksFragment">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout_info"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager_info"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

In my Fragment file, inside onCreateView() method, I set up both ViewPager and TabLayout:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_links, container, false);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout_info);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);


    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager_info);
    PagerAdapterLinks adapter = new PagerAdapterLinks(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


    return view;
}
```

On android 5 and higher everything works just fine, and I can change between tabs using swipe, or by clicking on tab name. However, on lower android version, clicking on tabs doen't do anything, and the only way to change pages in ViewPager is by swiping. How can I make my TabLayout work on android including 4.1 and 4.4?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Using `addOnTabSelectedListener` like so:

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab) {
         switch(tab.getPosition()) {
             case 0:
                // ...
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add android.support.design.widget.TabLayout, which will be used for rendering the different tab options. The android.support.v4.view.ViewPager component will be used to page between the various fragments we will create.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />
```

Now that we have the ViewPager and our tabs in our layout, we should start defining the content of each of the tabs. Since each tab is just a fragment being displayed, we need to create and define the Fragment to be shown. You may have one or more fragments in your application depending on your requirements.

In res/layout/fragment_page.xml define the XML layout for the fragment which will be displayed on screen when a particular tab is selected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

In `PageFragment.java` define the inflation logic for the fragment of tab content:

```
// In this case, the fragment displays simple text based on the page
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

    private int mPage;

    public static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
        PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view;
        textView.setText("Fragment #" + mPage);
        return view;
    }
}
```

The next thing to do is to implement the adapter for your ViewPager which controls the order of the tabs, the titles and their associated content. The most important methods to implement here are `getPageTitle(int position)` which is used to get the title for each tab and getItem(int position) which determines the fragment for each tab.

```
public class SampleFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
    private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3" };
    private Context context;

    public SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PageFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        return tabTitles[position];
    }
}
```

Finally, we need to attach our ViewPager to the SampleFragmentPagerAdapter and then configure the sliding tabs with a two step process:

In the `onCreate()` method of your activity, find the `ViewPager` and connect the adapter.
Set the `ViewPager` on the `TabLayout` to connect the pager with the tabs.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), 
            MainActivity.this));

        // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

}
```

Source : https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout

Comment: I'm not looking for a full tutorial, I want to know how to make this method compatible with API16. What You pasted is the same as my code, and it won't work below android 4.4